# QT widgets vs QT GUI

Tags: c++, xml, qt, user-interface, widget

I'm new at QT, actually I didn't start yet but I'm intending to create a xml file (markups and nodes and everything .. ) from a QT user interface.

For example the user can find in my interface text fields where he can insert an employee name, id and age and my program will turn that to an employee node in my output xml file with its attributes name , id , age. so since I'm coding with c++ I wanted to create this interface   as a QT GUI but I found that QT creator provides a project named QT Widget with the same option.

So I'm kind of confused now and I don't know what's the difference between them so I can chose.
I will appreciate any help from guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly: a Qt Widget is a tiny element, one of the many items in a gui (buttons, comboboxes are all widgets). The Qt Widget, project type is for creating one, which you can use in a separate projects interface.

A Qt Gui is more likely the project type you want, that will allow you to drag in many widgets to create your 'interface text fields'.

You would use a Qt Widget project type if you need to do more advanced customization or create your own text field control.

Comment: I don't think this is what they meant. In Qt Creator's "Create Project" dialog there is a category called Qt Widget Project which has "Qt Gui Application" and "Mobile Qt Application" as choices. Another category is "Qt Quick Project" which I'm guessing they are asking about. If you want a QWidget based project, you choose it as the base class in the Qt GUI application wizard, but I don't think they even got that far...

Comment: thanks I think I'm gonna go for a Widget Project - "Qt Gui Application" cause it sounds simpler and less error generating than coding with QML !

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Qt Quick vs. Qt Widgets?

Qt Quick is a more recent type of Qt GUI which is created from a declarative markup languages known as QML. The QML source is interpreted at run-time as opposed to Qt Widgets which are compiled from C++ source code into native executable code. In addition to QML, Qt Quick uses inline Javascript for scripting the UI, but it can be (and usually is) interfaced from C++ for more complex processing.

EDIT: Qt Quick is also very much touch-oriented (at least at its current state) whereas Qt Widget GUIs provide a much richer set of UI elements. So if you are making a desktop application, you might want to leave Qt Quick alone.

Comment: so QML is something like XAML language in DotNET where I can use it for binding data with my input components, so for a beginner is it really recommended to start with QML ?

Comment: In a way it's similar. But QML is much more limited than XAML. XAML is actually probably closer to Qt's .ui files. They are XML files that are used to store the forms created in Qt Designer, usually not manipulated directly by hand. Qt Creator doesn't even let you edit the .ui files except in Qt Designer.

Comment: Take a look at the list of QML components here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeelements.html If you think those are suitable for your needs, by all means use it. You can always embed a QML element inside a GUI made with Qt Designer, for instance. To make a specific example, there is no direct "push button" element in Qt. Instead, you would just use combine some graphical element such as Rectangle or Image with a MouseArea and make it behave like a button.